# Downloading xlwt to Python 3.5.1

Tags: python, python-3.5, xlwt

I'm trying to download the package xlwt to my Python 3.5.1 but typing `'pip install xlwt'` isn't working and gives me an error at the word `install` that says invalid syntax, though all the websites I've checked told me to do exactly this.

I mostly have a theoretical knowledge of Python and can code pretty decently, but don't really know how to set the technology up in order to do the actual coding.

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: What happens when you type just  'pip'   and  enter. Are you on windows or something else

Comment: Are you using pip3?  If on linux you might need sudo first

Comment: When I just type 'pip' and enter it tells me pip is not defined. Do I have to complete another step for this to work?

Comment: On Windows, in a cmd.exe console, not Python prompt, `py -m pip install xlwt`.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out! I found the command prompt...I did not understand this before

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are typing `pip install ...` into a Python prompt and not a shell command prompt. This is not a Python statement but a shell command that has to be executed at the command-line prompt.

Comment: I'm typing this directly into my Python 3.5.1 Shell...is this not the correct place?

Comment: if you have >>> at the cursor, then no.  ctl-d and you will be at os prompt.  pip from there

Comment: No, it's not the correct place. Do you start the Python shell by typing `python` or some other way?